# What is the best Practise for this Android Layout, should I use nested Fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want this layout in Android:

[image]

What is the best approach to design this?

I currently have a `LinearLayout` with Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 taking half of the space as you can see.

Now how can I render Fragment 3, as you can see it has **half** the height of Fragment 1, without using nested weights? I am already using weights for LinearLayout and Fragment 1 and 2.

Again same goes with the TextureView, how can I make it have half the **width** and **height** of fragment 3? I think it should be easy to center.

Do I need to use nested weights here?

Is it a good practice to initialize the dimensions of Fragment 3 and TextureView on Runtime?

Thanks